# Check if a rectangle bisects another rectangle

Tags: algorithm, shapes

I have two rectangles on a grid, defined by x, y, width, and height (all integers).

I want to tell if one of them *bisects* the other. That is, not just overlaps, but goes all the way through so as to create three rectangles.

Example:
[image: Overlap vsbisect]

Is there a relatively time-efficient algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the second example in your question, we can find the following conditions to determine if rectangle `A` bisects rectangle `B` vertically:

```
xA <= xB && xA + widthA >= xB + widthB && yA > yB && yA + heightA < yB + heightB
```

Similarly, there are three more cases (horizontal and the same for the other way around). If any of these cases apply, you have a bisection.